# How do I declare a 2d array in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess, pseudocode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77saS.png)

How on earth do I declare this ? Using the code
"temperature[6,2]"
probably wouldn't work as it starts from 0

HELP!

Comment: Could we please see the code you are using

Comment: It is from scratch. I am using pseudocode to later use in python. There is an image attached.

Comment: Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. Images can not be pasted into our IDEs and the links can go stale.

Comment: As for Arrays, you can use a 1-dim list that you partition yourself or a list of lists (or dicts) or create a class that wraps that or look for a module that does it for you or use something like numpy.... brooooaaaad possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. For static data I would do it this way

```
temperature = [[6, 13, 5],
               [5, 12, 6],
               [9, 17, 8],
               [9, 20, 9],
               [7, 15, 6],
               [6, 13, 6],
               [7, 13, 6]]
```

Note that what you are actually doing here is making a 'list of lists'

```
>>> temperature[6]
[7, 13, 6]

>>> temperature[6][2]
6
```

Comment: thank you very much. Would you know how to search one's input in the array?

Comment: Example:  the array is numbers[2,101]  the first row is numbers 0 to 100 while the second is all empty strings. If the user input a number how can I search the array using their answer

Comment: @PapiHarpy `numbers[1][h]`

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayex = [[1, 2, 3],
           [2, 4, 6],
           [3, 6, 9],
           [4, 8, 12],
           [5, 10, 15],
           [6, 12, 18],
           [7, 14, 21]]
```

This is how I usually do mine